# Are there functions to request capacity for std::set?

Tags: c++, set

For `std::vector`, we can use `vector::reserve(n)` to request that the vector capacity be at least enough to contain n elements. So what about `std::set`? Do we have similar function to reserve its capability? I ask this question is because sometimes it is a request to allocate enough capability for std::set variable when it is used as a reference argument of a function, which comes from another dynamic library (Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) is used).

EDIT

One possible solution might be using get_allocator function:

```
std::set<float> abc;
    float *p;
    p = abc.get_allocator().allocate(100);
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        abc.insert(abc.end(),i);

    std::set<float>::iterator it = abc.begin();
    std::set<float>::iterator itEnd = abc.end();
    while(it != itEnd)
    {
        std::cout<<(*it)<<std::endl;
        it++;
    }

     abc.get_allocator().deallocate(p,100);
```

Comment: Is this somehow *not* addressed by looking at [the documentation for `std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) rather than posting here? Or is there something else you're looking for?

Comment: I don't think the code in your update will do what you expect - you're allocating a block of memory, but I'm not convinced it will be "assigned" to your set, which will allocate its own memory as needed. If it _does_ do what you expect, then it's dangerous as the set still thinks it has 100 valid items.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With a `std::vector`, it's important to provide functionality to `reserve` space, as it is guaranteed in the C++ standard that all elements in a vector be contiguous in memory.  This means that if you try to `push_back` more items than are currently reserved, there is a need to allocate more memory, potentially in a different place, and potentially having to move existing items (I think this is implementation based).  This all takes time, so instead you can reserve (or pre-allocate) the space you think you'll need.

Conversely, a container such as a `std::set` is *generally* implemented as a tree.  The main difference here is that elements are often allocated dynamically as they are added.  There is no requirement for items to be contiguous in memory, and so there is no need to "reserve" any space for said items - depending on the implementation, they can simply be allocated as they're needed, anywhere in available memory.

Not sure if that's the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks. One solution I can figure out is to use get_allocator().allocate() function. I have reorganized my question.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above, I don't think that will do what you expect. For a set, the only reason I can think of to pre-allocate the memory is if you need it to be a specific place (for example, mapped memory in an embedded system). In that case you'd likely need a custom allocator anyway.

Comment: It is very reasonable to expect `reserve` for any container data structure. If sequentially create millions of sets but know an upper bound for their size, then the desire to preallocate is very, very reasonable.